# Why don't I receive an email using codeigniter email library when using local server?

Tags: macos, codeigniter, localhost, email

I am using codeigniter's email library on mac os x apache 2 server. The weird thing I am running into is that when I use it on live server which is on hostgator.com the email goes through but when I run the same code on local apache2 server, I don't get any emails(even in spam box). What can be the problem? Here is the code

```
        $this->load->library('email');
        $this->email->from('your@example.com', 'Your Name');
        $this->email->to('myemailhere@gmail.com'); 
        $this->email->subject('Email Test');
        $this->email->message('Testing the email class.');  
        if($this->email->send())
        {    
            var_export($this->email->print_debugger());
        }
```

On both local and live server, this is var_dump data

```
'Your message has been successfully sent using the following protocol: mail
From: "Your Name" 
Return-Path: 
Reply-To: "your@example.com" 
X-Sender: your@example.com
X-Mailer: CodeIgniter
X-Priority: 3 (Normal)
Message-ID: <5122a6ed242b8@example.com>
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
=?utf-8?Q?Email_Test?=
Testing the email class.
```

Comment: Your local apache server has to be set up to send real emails.

Comment: Do you have a link to a tutorial for this?

Comment: For @RocketHazmat to answer you have to provide us with more information about your local environment. Are you developing on Windows/Mac/Linux?

Comment: Yea I am on Mac. 10.7.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just try this.

Specify path for send mail in php.ini

```
sendmail_path = "path/to/php path/to/sendmail.php"
```

The second step - you can try to use this script

```
define('DIR','path/to/sendmail_dir');
$stream = '';
$fp = fopen('php://stdin','r');
while ($t = fread($fp,2048)) {
    if ($t === chr(0)) {
        break;
    }
    $stream .= $t;
}
fclose($fp);

$fp = fopen(mkname(),'w');
fwrite($fp,$stream);
fclose($fp);

function mkname($i = 0) {
    $fn = DIR.date('Y-m-d_H-i-s_').$i.'.eml';
    if (file_exists($fn)) {
        return mkname(++$i);
    } else {
        return $fn;
    }
}
```